# How to type cast int division to floating point?

Tags: c++, static-cast

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
 
 float f=static_cast<float>(5/2);
 printf("%f",f);
 
 return 0;
}
```

The answer is always 2.0.
I searched before asking but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You're performing integer division *before* casting to `float`, so you're casting result of the integer division.  If you want to do floating point division, you need to divide floating point values in the first place.

Comment: `float f = 5.f / 2.f;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

 float f=(float)5/(float)2;
printf("%f",f);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do

```
float f = 5.0f / 2;
```

In your code, `5` and `2` are `int`s, so in `5/2` the `/` operator is the integer division operator; the result will always be an integer, in this case, `2`. Only then is it converted to `float`, giving `2.0`.

You need to do floating point division, so at least one of the operands needs to be of floating point type. You could just write `5.0`, without the `f`, but that would have type `double` by default, and the result will then be converted to `float` - a conversion that can cause issues (not here for these particular constant values, but still, it's better to use the right type in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {

    float f = 5.0 / 2;
    printf("%f", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: comma in `printf` not period.

Comment: Strict speaking `5.0` is a double and you then cast to float. To do float division you'd want `5.f` (or `5.0f`).